# Using chernoff bounds on grid/subgrid system

Tags: probability, statistics

I understand the basic concept of Chernoff bounds, but I am uncertain about how to apply it to the below problem. The grid thing is what's really throwing me off, I don't really see how to visualize/set up the problem in a way that will work nicely with Chernoff bounds. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

> A certain city is experiencing a big crime wave. The city decides that
>   it needs to put its police officers out into the streets to bring back
>   security. The city is conveniently arranged into a 100 * 100 grid of
>   streets. Each street intersection can be identified by two integers
>   (a, b)where $1\leq a \leq 100$ and $B \leq b \leq 100$. The city only
>   has 1000 police officers, so it decides to send each police officer to
>   a uniformly random grid location, independent of each other. The city
>   wants to make sure that every 20 * 20 subgrid (corresponding to grid
>   points (a, b) with $A \leq a \leq A + 19$ and $B \leq b \leq B + 19$
>   for valid A, B) gets more than 10 police officers.
>
> 1) Use the Chernoff bound to compute the probability that a single
>   subgrid gets at most 10 police officers.
>
> 2) Use the union bound together with the result from above to
>   calculate the probability that the city fails to meet its goal

Comment: For each subgrid, the number of police officers is the sum of $1000$ independent Bernoulli variables which denotes whether each officer is in the sub grid or not.  Therefore, you can apply a Chernoff's bound on it.